# Media player always loop and never stop

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I tried to play audio `once` when `Enter` key event occur on `EditText`.

But the Media player plays `looping` the audio and `never stop`. And `Media Player` didn't call `setOnCompletionListener` method.

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                        //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, editText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("oxygen.ogg");
                        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                        mp.setLooping(false);
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                Log.i("ONComplete Media palyer", "onComplete hit");
                                mp.stop();
                                mp.release();
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `setOnSeekCompleteListener` method instead of `setOnCompletionListener`. It plays once and complete stop now.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a similar issue.
Setting `mediaPlayer.isLooping = false` (kotlin) worked only when I created MediaPlayer from a resource:

```
MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.music).
```

It had no effect when I used URI

```
MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(myUri))
```

A possible workaround can be built with `CountDownTimer`

```kotlin
    setAlarmStopperTimer(musicPlayer, delay = musicPlayer.duration.toLong())

    .....

    private fun setAlarmStopperTimer(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer, delay: Long) {
        alarmStopperTimer = object : CountDownTimer(delay, 100) {
            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            override fun onFinish() {
                mediaPlayer.stop()
            }

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            }
        }
        alarmStopperTimer.start()
    }
```

Comment: same for me, using `new MediaPlayer()` instead of `MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(myUri))` solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepareAsync()` with `setOnPreparedListener()` and when media is ready then play it.

```
 try {
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("oxygen.ogg");
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            mp.setLooping(false);
            mp.prepareAsync();
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.i("ONComplete Media palyer", "onComplete hit");
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```